# add text layer in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers, coordinates

I have a text file that contains longitude and latitude of some items. How can i load this file onto a map?

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var attribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
                                    collapsible: false
                                });
                                var maptwo = new ol.Map({
                                    target: 'maptwo',
                                    layers: [
                                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                                        })
                                    ],
                                    controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution: false}).extend([attribution]),
                                    view: new ol.View({
                                        center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                                        zoom: 2
                                    })
                                });
</script>

                            <style>
                                .maptwo {
                                    height: 100%;
                                    width:100%;
                                }
                            </style>
```

Comment: IT might help to post your text data or a sample of it. By the way, your tag says OpenLayers 2 but you appear to be using version 3.

Comment: You are loading ol2 library. Then you use ol3 code to init your map, layers and controls and then you use ol2 code to init yourLocation. This should create a dozen of errors within firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [this OpenLayers 3 sample](https://rawgit.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-extras-demos/master/tsv/demo-tsv.html) I produced some time ago. It relies on the library [`csv2geojson`](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson).

I choose this solution because there are no native CSV support in OpenLayers 3 but GeoJSON is well supported.